# Downloading and running a custom set of scripts in the cobbler kickstart file for Fedora

Tags: fedora, kickstart, cobbler

I need to use rysnc to get a series of files from a server on the network in the cobbler kickstart file. Can I just add the rsync command line to the file to be run in the %post section of the file or is there something else that I need to be doing? Then once they are downloaded is it just a question of running the scripts or do I need to set permissions etc first?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can just download them (with rsync or via any other method) and run them. They'll need to have the normal permissions any script might need.

Are you trying this and encountering a problem?